# Pass props to all of its children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm implementing a nested component and all of my components need to have **variable** prop, now I have:

```
<Parent variable="myVariable">
   <Child1 variable="myVariable" />
   <Child2 variable="myVariable" />
</Parent>
```

But I don't want to pass the prop directly to each component and I need something like this:

```
<Parent variable="myVariable">
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

and I need to get access to **variable prop** from **Child1** and **Child2**.

Comment: Perhaps implementing the Parent as a HoC which passes the prop to it's children might help?

Comment: You might want to try a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: You could also look into [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which is no longer experimental.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is two solutions to do this. Using **React.createContext** or **React.cloneElement** in your Parent component.

> I highly recommend using **React.createContext** in **React 16.3+** since this is exactly what React Context is meant for. Its also especially helpful if you have **flow** to keep `prop` type checking working properly.
>
> Note in **React 16.6** its even easier to use context by using **contextType**.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

(or using create-react-context https://github.com/jamiebuilds/create-react-context) if you're not up to date.

```
// parentFile.js
import * as React from 'react';

export const MyContext = React.createContext(); // React.createContext accepts a defaultValue as the first param

type Props = {
  variable: string,
  children: React.Node
};

class Parent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
       <MyContext.Provider value={{ variable: this.props.variable }}>
         {this.props.children}
       </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends Component<{}> {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.context.variable}</div>);
  }
}

// IF you have a child in a different file make sure you import the correct consumer
// child2.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './parentFile';

class Child2 extends Component<{}> {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    return (<span>{this.context.variable}</span>);
  }
}
```

React.createContext shines here where you can handle nested components

```
// Example of using Parent and Child

import * as React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<{}> {

  render() {
    <Parent variable="test">
      <Child1 />
      { /* Previously you couldn't use 
           React.cloneElement to handle the nested case */ }
      <SomeOtherComp>
        <Child2 />
      </SomeOtherComp>
    </Parent>
  }
}
```

> This is a quick example of how to do this without **React Context** and using **React.cloneElement**

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children, props } = this.props;
    return (
      React.Children.map(children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {...props})
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: clould you please provide a jsx example?

Comment: This is exactly what `createContext ` was designed for. Another option is to use Redux to handle the information, but that's a big commitment if you aren't already implementing Redux in your app.

Comment: @KennethTruong What if we have dynamic Child component? For example I want to have AnotherChild Component. Should I add another ChildConsumer for this component? Because I mentioned <Child1 /> and <Child2 />. but in that example I can see only <Child />
Actually I want to get access to variable in each child component not just <Child />

Comment: Actually after thinking about it. If you have a dynamic child you would have to add the ChildConsumer into all your child components. Or you can always use my 2nd solution which should work with dynamic children.

Comment: Another option for dynamic components is to provide the React.Element into the props but I recommend just using ChildConsumer on whichever Child Components needs it

Comment: Yup ReactContext can be used by nested components! Just use the same ContextConsumer

Comment: I updated my example to show Child1, Child2 and a NestedComponent. Let me know if this helps

Comment: What if Child1 and Child2 are in different files? All the examples I see assume they reside in the same file. I'm having issues getting this to work when children are in other files.

Comment: @jamesemanon if the children are in different files. You have to make sure you export the ChildConsumer and import the same one in your different child files.

Comment: // parentFile.js
const { Provider, Consumer } from React.createContext();
export const SomeConsumer = Consumer;

// Child 1 File
import { SomeConsumer } from 'parentFile';

// Child 2 File
 import { SomeConsumer } from 'parentFile';

Comment: yeah, I ended going down that route, but that seems so .... blah. One might has well create their own subscriber (pub/sub) and this seems to be the same thing right? So, for every createContext usage, we have to have a seperate file to export it out? Seems kinda invasive? no?

Comment: If you created your own pub/sub you would have more boilerplate code. (Since you have to call setState etc and make the pub/sub part of the React life cycle. While this will automatically render when the provider changes value.)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the children as props to parent:

```
   class Wrapper extends React.Component {
     render() {
      return (
        this.props.wraps.map(El => <El {...this.props} />);
     };
    }
  }
```

So you can do:

```
  <Wrapper wraps = {[Child1, Child2]} variable = "whatever" />
```

Comment: Actually I need to keep my DOM structure